# LinkedBlockingQueue - producer/consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have 2 threads in a simple producer-consumer scenario managed around a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

In the consumer thread I use `take()` i.e. I want to block the consumer while an element comes into the queue.

Is it OK if in the producer thread I use `offer()` to add to the queue, and not `put()`? Would that cause any problems?

I mean, does using `take()` imply I should be also using `put`?

I guess not but I want to be fully sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no problem using `offer` on the producer whatever you use at the consumer end.

This would be a common mechanism to allow the producer to push to one of a number of queues, it could call `offer` on each queue until it succeeds. It could even call `put` on the last queue.

Answer (score 0):

`offer` and `put` differ only in that, `put` will wait for a full queue to have space, while `offer` (with optional timeout) will simply return false (without adding the item) if the queue is full (and `add` will throw an exception).

So long as your code respects these differences, then there are no problems with whichever method you use (though of course, there will be times when one is better for a certain task).